# How to solve TS2349 in a protractor test model

Tags: protractor, typescript-typings

I've got the following test setup, but the transpiler is giving me the following error:

> Error:(108, 9) TS2349:Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((opt_callback?: (value: Model1[]) => R | IThenable, opt_errback?: (error: any...' has no compatible call signatures.

// action class

```
export class SearchResultsActions {
    // setup and other stuff

    // Model1 and Model2 are both interfaces
    getJSON(): promise.Promise<Array<Model1>> | promise.Promise<Array<Model2>> {
        return option.getText().then((selected: string) => {
            let searchType: "model1" | "model2"  = "model1";
            if (selected === "Model 2") {
                searchType = "model2";
            }

            // getResultsEl returns an ElementArrayFinder
            return ResultsPage.getResultsEl().map((el, index) => {
                let pageObject: Model1PageObject | Model2PageObject = SearchPage.getResult(searchType, index);
                let actionObject: Model1Actions | Model2Actions;

                if (searchType === "model1") {
                    actionObject = new Model1Actions(<Model1PageObject> pageObject);
                } else {
                    actionObject = new Model2Actions(<Model2PageObject> pageObject)
                }

                // both Model1Actions and Model2Actions have a getJSON() method
                return actionObject.getJSON(); // returns a JSON object
            });
        });
    }
}
```

In the search spec where the error is:

```
SearchResultsActions.getJSON()
    .then((res: Array<Model1> | Array<Model2>) => {
        // use lodash to perform equality
        expect(_.isEqual(res, expected)).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

The curious thing is, despite the error, the transpile works anyway and the tests pass.  But I would like to not have the error blaring at me.

I'm using typescript 2.3.3, protractor 5.1.2

Any thoughts?  Anywhere I can clarify?

Comment: The answer, which I'll add as an answer as soon as I can, is to set the return type for `getJSON() to getJSON(): promise.Promise<Array<Model1> | Array<Model2>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to change the return type to

```
promise.Promise<Array<Model1> | Array<Model2>>
```

which is different from

```
promise.Promise<Array<Model1>> | promise.Promise<Array<Model2>>
```

which doesn't work.

Apparently this is true for Observables as well.